# HTML not displaying for DIV

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have HTML code with some DIV's and javascripts:

```html
<div class="blabla">
anything here
</div>

<script>setText('<p>MY TEXT 1</p>');</script>

<div id="textcomeshere"></div>

<script>setText('<p>MY TEXT 2</p>');</script>
```

This is my `setText` function:

```js
function setText(txt) {
  console.log(txt);
  $("#textcomeshere").html(txt);
}
```

The problem is, nothing appears inside div.

I also tried to add `$( document ).ready()` to that function, but then the first `setText` is called before document load and it doesn't work. If I use it without document.ready, the first `setText` is called before the `#textcomeshere DIV` exists, so it doesn't work.

I need to keep the order in code as it is (as there are more conditions), so I can't move the setText calls to other place, neither the textcomeshere DIV, as it has his position there.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Did you properly link your JavaScript file in the HTML?

Comment: "I need to keep the order in code as it is (as there are more conditions), so I can't move the setText calls to other place" - This seems odd, you might want to reconsider how your code is laid out.

Comment: seems you haven't added jQuery

Comment: I have added jquery, just not mentioned in my code here. If I put the setText function at the beginning of the code, it can't find my DIV id. If I put the function at the end of my code, the setText is called before the function exists. So neither any of these solutions are working. The #textcomeshere DIV must be in the middle of the screen, between other divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing what helped me, was to move all setText calls after the textcomeshere div and the jquery function in the beginning of the code. This way it works, however not an ideal solution, if I need to call setText before showing some other divs etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setText(txt) {
            console.log(txt);
            $("#textcomeshere").html(txt);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="blabla">
        anything here
    </div>

    <script>setText('<p>MY TEXT 1</p>');</script>

    <div id="textcomeshere"></div>

    <script>setText('<p>MY TEXT 2</p>');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also your first settext() call inside `<body>` can't change `<div>` contents because `<div id="textcomeshere">` is defined after it. `<script>` inside the body of html document executed in the manner they are defined in DOM(Document Object Model).

Comment: for some reason this shows nothing in my code, however I used it same way. I am going to investigate

Comment: exactly for the reason you wrote - first settext() call inside <body> can't change <div> contents because <div id="textcomeshere"> is defined after it. But how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>project 11</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="blabla">
        anything here
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setText("p", 'MY TEXT 1');
        });
    </script>
    <div id="textcomeshere"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setText("p", 'MY TEXT 2');
        });
    </script>

    <script src="assets/js/text.js"></script>
    <!-- main javaScript file-->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript file

```
  /**
 * 
 * text.js
 */

    let myDiv = document.getElementById("textcomeshere"),
        myTag, myTextNode;
    
    function setText(tag, txt) {
        myTag = document.createElement(tag); // create tag
        console.log(myTag); // result <p></p> in case tag was p
        myTextNode = document.createTextNode(txt); // create text
        console.log(myTextNode); // result will be text 
        myTag.appendChild(myTextNode) // appending the textNode to the tag
        myDiv.appendChild(myTag); // appending the tag with it's text content to the div
        console.log(myDiv); // div now has p tag and text inside of it
    }
```

[image: result]

Comment: document.write will not write the text inside that DIV I want

Comment: oh my bad. Sorry.

Comment: I updated my answer is this what you are looking for? I also made some adjustments to the method.

Comment: actually this seems working for me, if you put to every setText call $(document).read, however this seems like overkill for showing a text in div. But at least it is a working example, so thank you for your help, I appreciate it. For now I solved it by moving all setText calls after the textcomeshere div and the jquery function in the beginning of the code, to avoid using document ready for each element,

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

i think calling your JS file in head just after jQuery CDN will resolve this problem...

Comment: doesn't help. I need to call setText multiple times from various places.

Comment: I already solved it - I put all the calls after the div, because they were called when the div was not created yet, so it worked not. I didn't have better solution, but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

js file & html file.

```js
document.getElementById("textcomeshere").innerHTML = "update text here";
```

```html
<div class="blabla">
anything here
</div>

<div id="textcomeshere"></div>
```

Try This. It will work

Comment: not working in my code, it is same as with jquery just with js